# Using --sort-by with kubectl get pods --all-namespaces to sort by both namespace AND name doesn't work

Tags: sorting, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm guessing at this point the answer is a big fat NO. I'm reaching the hive mind here for a clear answer of why, or in case I'm wrong (which I really hope I am) for a concrete example.

I've been able to use `jq` successfully, but I am hoping I'm just missing something in the jsonpath syntax of `--sort-by`.

## What I know

Accoridng to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#sorting-list-objects)(also quoted below) `kubectl`'s `--sort-by` argument takes a jsonpath syntax.

> #### Sorting list objects
>
> To output objects to a sorted list in your terminal window, you can add the `--sort-by` flag to a supported kubectl command. Sort your objects by specifying any numeric or string field with the `--sort-by flag`. To specify a field, use a [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) expression.
>
> Syntax
>
> `kubectl [command] [TYPE] [NAME] --sort-by=<jsonpath_exp>`

I've looked at their jsonpath examples, and while it seems I am able to use the syntax to output what I think would be a sortable object, in effect I get a blank output.

Maybe if the output could be concated/transformed into a string, instead of an array/list, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Can anyone confirm success of using `--sort-by` with multiple fields?

### What I've tried

#### Example of successful jsonpath output:

```
$ kubectl get --namespace ix-authentik pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}[{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name}]{end}" && echo
[<namespace a>,<pod a1>][<namespace a>,<pod a2>][<namespace b>,<pod b1>....
```

#### Example of a failed sort-by attempts based on the syntax above:

```
$ kubectl get --all-namespaces pods --sort-by="{range .}[{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name}]{end}"
No resources found

$ kubectl get --all-namespaces pods --sort-by="[{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name}]"
# Randomly sorted mess

$ kubectl get --all-namespaces pods --sort-by="{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name}"
# Sorted only by namespace

$ kubectl get --all-namespaces pods --sort-by=".metadata.namespace,.metadata.name"
No resources found

$ kubectl get --all-namespaces pods --sort-by="[.metadata.namespace,.metadata.name]"
No resources found
```

### Resources I've reviewed

The kubernates GitHub repo has several issues about sort, there is even a closed PR from 2019 where they were about to deprecate the --sort-by featrue because it was terrible.
But nothing I could easily find on multiple values. (I might be searching all wrong though)

I've even tried Bing Chat's AI to resolve this, it suggest syntax similar to above, but it only sorts on the first column. AI can't figure out questions that havn't been answered (properly) yet (surprise, surprise), so I'm reaching out to the human driven hive mind.

Comment: I don't see any indication that `--sort-by` is expected to work with multiple fields. The description ("...The field in the API resource specified by this JSONPath expression must be an integer or a string.") strongly suggests that it only supports a single field.

Comment: I would agree... And it seems that the flavor of JSONPath used by k8s, does not have a way to compose a string (or concat) from values.